# How to get correct character-encoding between mysql and filemaker

Tags: php, character-encoding, filemaker

I'm unsure if this is a php-, filemaker-, mysql- or an odbc driver issue.

For security reasons the input fields of my current php webform convert special characters into hex codes, (for example: # becomes `&#39;` ) This hex code is saved in the database and will also be shown in Filemaker11 as the hex code. This is not what i want. 
How can I make sure the special character will be displayed as it should be?

The other way round (from filemaker to db), no conversion will be done on inserting the special characters.

How can I make sure everything will be consistent?

Kind regards,
Jeroen

Comment: What do you mean "for security reasons"? Doing that conversion doesn't help security. And who or what is doing the conversion anyway?

Comment: Oh, you mean percent encoding? Like a space becomes %20 ? PHP automatically decodes them, although you can do it manually too. They are not converted for security, they are converted because they are can't be put in a url. I think you will need to give us more details - for example what the output looks like, the source code, things like that.

Comment: chars like ", ' #" are converted to hex. I thought this had to do with the security.

The filtered var for inserting into the DP is:
$insert_voornaam = filter_var($_POST['voornaam'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

after that, the insert will be prepared: 
$stmt->bindParam(':voornaam', $insert_voornaam, PDO::PARAM_STR);

and executed:
$stmt->execute();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! It appeared that I had to add an extra line to my PHP script.

after setting up the connection, php needs to tell mysql what the encoding needs to be. This can be done with the following line:

```
$dbh->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Thanks for the effort guys!

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker is just showing the data stored in MySQL. If you pull up the DB in a tool like PhpMyAdmin you should see that the varchar contains the encoding as well. Since FMP is looking at it simply as a text field, it shows the encoding that was stored. If you wanted to decode in FMP you could show a calc field of the varchar that has a custom function to decode the text. (but that won't allow for updating the data..) You could also try a trigger on record load to decode the data in the fields so that you can properly view/edit.

Answer (score 0):

This: `&#39;` type of encoding is not done automatically by the browser. Something is doing it. Normally you do it only on *output* not on input.

You can use `html_entity_decode()` to undo it. But I strongly suggest you figure out why it's happening in the first place.

Comment: That's right, the encoding happens on _output_. 
The problem is that Filemaker will not decode it, so it will be shown as `&#39;`.

Comment: I don't get it - filemaker is reading in html? How could something read in html and not support entities?

Comment: Filemaker does no HTML reading. It just displays the characters from the DB's VARCHAR fields without decoding.

Comment: When I said output I mean output to the browser, not to the DB. You should not be encoding characters before sending them to the DB.

Comment: Does the encoding happens on the var filtering:?? FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING

See: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: Yup, seems that way - good catch. I've never used filtering, so I was not familiar with it. Hmm, are you passing any flag to it? It seems that it only encodes if it's asked to. I'm not really sure. I personally think you don't need it, but I don't know your application, so I can't say for sure.